# Need Powershell script to get the information from a description field using a text file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have users assigned to computers. The association is included in the Description field of the computer object. So it looks like:

```
department, user's firstname lastname, serial number, location.
```

I have a .ps1 script I use to get an individual user's computer. For the life of me, I can't get the script to pull a list of users from a txt or csv file and return the computers.

I have tried numerous variations of this using `Get-Content` and `Import-Csv`:

```
$a = Import-Csv C:\temp\getusers.csv |
    Get-ADComputer * -Filter "Description -Like '*$a*'" -properties Name,description |
    Select Name, Description | Sort-Object Name
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [1] what is the format of the `GetUsers.txt` file? [2] how is `$a` getting into the pipeline?

Comment: Hi Theo -- welcome to SO.  Can you provide some more detail?  Also, your code is wrong.  You either need to truncate after .csv and put the rest on another line with $a | in front or you need to remove $a = and use the magic variable $_ for Get-ADComputer

Comment: also, PLEASE format your code ... the page where you entered the question has a link to  the formatting instructions. [*grin*]

Comment: The format of the getusers.txt is: first lastname : each on a separate line.

Comment: @thepip3r - I'm not sure what you mean by truncate after .csv. And Get-ADComputer after the | is on a separate line.